# Django prevent duplicate queries after prefetch related

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a fairly simple library project in Django, here are my models, a book can have many copies and each copy can have many loans.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', related_name='books')

    @property
    def is_available(self):
        """Returns True if the Book has any available copies"""
        return self.copies.exclude(loans__returned=False).exists()


class BookCopy(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', related_name='copies')

class Loan(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    returned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                 null=True, related_name='loans')
    book_copy = models.ForeignKey(
        'BookCopy', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='loans')
```

I have a fairly simple view containing a list of books

```
def book_list(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.prefetch_related('authors', 'copies__loans')
    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', {'books': books})
```

To figure out if a book is available I've written the property `is_available` inside the Book model. However when I call this property inside my template with the following:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {% if not book.is_available %}
       -- Template stuff --
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

According to Django Debug Toolbar I end up with a duplicate query for every Book in the queryset

[image]

Reading the Django documentation for [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) there's a section discribing the behaviour which I think may be the culprit

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.

How would I prevent these duplicate queries from occuring?

Comment: can you state the problem you are trying to solve with your code?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem